# Get current day using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the current date using JavaScript. Is it possible to do that?

I want to add classes to some DOM element and it depends of the day of the week. Which element should I add to this class?

Comment: What do you mean by WordPress current day ?

Comment: May be using the wordpress date functions

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date or go with http://momentjs.com if you want to get fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've an approach for you, getting the WordPress date in JavaScript, a numb one, but still an approach: :)

#### functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse-custom-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/wpse-custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );

wp_localize_script(
    'wpse-custom-scripts',
    'wpse',
    array(
        'date_time_now' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ), //format: YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00
    )
);
```

#### wpse-custom.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log("WordPress date now: " + wpse.date_time_now);
});
```

It's not a better approach, I know.